# Python for-loop to change row value based on a condition works correctly but does not change the values on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am just getting into Python, and I am trying to make a `for-loop` that loops on every row and randomly select two columns on each iteration based on a given condition and change their values. The `for-loop` works without any problems; however, the results don't change on the `dataframe`.

A reproducible example:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,40,10,20,10],
                  'B': [10,10,50,40,50],
                  'C': [10,20,10,10,10],
                  'D': [10,30,10,10,50],
                  'E': [10,10,40,10,10],
                  'F': [2,3,2,2,3]})

df:


    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   10  10  10  10  10  2
1   40  10  20  30  10  3
2   10  50  10  10  40  2
3   20  40  10  10  10  2
4   10  50  10  50  10  3
```

This is my `for-loop`; the for loop iterates on all rows and check if the value on column F = 2; it randomly selects two columns with value 10 and change them to 100.

```
for index, i in df.iterrows():
  if i['F'] == 2:
    i[i==10].sample(2, axis=0)+100
    print(i[i==10].sample(2, axis=0)+100)
```

This is the output of the loop:

```
E    110
C    110
Name: 0, dtype: int64
C    110
D    110
Name: 2, dtype: int64
C    110
D    110
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

This is what the `dataframe` is expected to look like:

```
df:


    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   10  10  110 10  110 2
1   40  10  20  30  10  3
2   10  50  110 110 40  2
3   20  40  110 110 10  2
4   10  50  10  50  10  3
```

However, the columns on the `dataframe` are not change. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```py
i[i==10].sample(2, axis=0)+100
```

`.sample` returns a new dataframe so the original dataframe (`df`) was not updated at all.

Try this:

```py
for index, i in df.iterrows():
    if i['F'] == 2:
        cond = (i == 10)

        # You can only sample 2 rows if there are at
        # least 2 rows meeting the condition
        if cond.sum() >= 2:
            idx = i[cond].sample(2).index
            i[idx] += 100
            print(i[idx])
```

Comment: Works as intended, thank you very much. Just a question, what if we want to exclude a column from the sample, for example, column E or D and E?

Comment: You change the condition: `cond = (i == 10) & not i.index.isin(['E', 'D', 'F'])`

Comment: It didnt work `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` the error was from not. I tried changing `&` to `and` showed an error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
I also tried using `not in` and adding `( )` ,but none of them worked.

Comment: I meant in my first comment. What if I want the loop to skip specific columns so their values don't change; for example, column E has 10, but the loop should skip it (exclude it) from the loop, and its value should not be changed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You [should not modify the original df in place](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). Make a copy and iterate:

```
df2 = df.copy()
for index, i in df.iterrows():
    if i['F'] == 2:
        s = i[i==10].sample(2, axis=0)+100
        df2.loc[index,i.index.isin(s.index)] = s
```